# When choosen the same device for input (MIcrophone) and output (speaker) audio the quality of the speaker ist bad

Tags: sound, microphone, headphones, speakers

i have the problem when i use the same devices (in my case a headset) as the microphone and the speaker, the audio quality of the speaker gets very bad. When I than switch the microphone to another device, the sound gets better.

I have tested I with two different devices (Jabra Link 380 and Lgitech Zone Vibe 125).
Does someone know this problem?

Have a nice day